# How can I get a report of which elements / structures are causing large DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a web app that has loads of DOM elements, and it's causing the browser to slow down.

I would like to know what the culprit is. It's trivial to write a bit of javascript to loop through all DOM elements and report on which tags are used the most, but I'm looking for something a little more sophisticated. Let's say for example that the following structure appears a thousand times:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="somestuff">
    <ul>
      <li>Only one item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Doing a "report" on how many times a tag is used might show the `div` tag as being used a lot, which in a large app doesn't tell me much if it is used often outside that structure, which is pretty likely for most apps.

What I'd like is something that detects and reports that the above structure occurs 1000 times. Again, it might be easy enough to report on tag+class, but I'm guessing that there are instances where such a simplistic approach would have trouble detecting what I'm trying to find, just for example when there is no class. Are there any tools / scripts already out there? Or approaches others have used to find the culprit in a situation similar to this?

Comment: Why would there be a specific culprit?  If you have a large DOM tree, that by nature would slow things down.  There probably isn't a culprit here, but you may want to attempt to refine your approach to accessing the DOM.  For instance, you could use document fragments as a way of processing a section of the application: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about document fragments. Let's assume that upon analysis we can eliminate some of the DOM elements in the repeated structure. Or even make decisions about dropping some features. We have static analysis tools for other languages, so I was hoping something like that might exist for the DOM.

Comment: "If you have a large DOM tree, that by nature would slow things down."

Or to put it another way, yes, agreed the large DOM tree could be slowing things down. We want to trim the tree, and the first step is to understand where it's overgrown.

Comment: I have reworded to make it clearer that we just want to *find* heavily repeated structures, and not that it is necessarily the culprit.